# In javascript why after reset the function's prototype need reset function prototype constructor too?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I always see code written like this:

```
function F() {};
var obj = {...}
F.prototype = obj;

F.prototype.constructor = F // why need this
```

After reseting the prototype: `F.prototype = obj`, why is the last line required? What does this reset the constructor too and is it always needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All **Javascript objects** inherit properties from the prototype object of their constructor.

Then, how do they also inherit properties from the Object class?

Remember that the prototype object is itself an object, it is created with the `Object()` constructor. This means that *the prototype object itself inherits properties from `Object.prototype`*.

If we use the default prototype object that is created when we define the **`F( )`** constructor, we get a subclass of Object.To get a subclass of `obj` here, we must explicitly create our prototype object.

```
function F() {}; 
  var obj = {...}
  F.prototype = obj();
```

Since the prototype object was created with the **`obj()`** constructor,it has a constructor property that refers to the constructor of `obj` object.But we want **`F` objects** to have a different constructor that is `F()`.That's why we've got to reassign this default constructor property.

```
 F.prototype.constructor = F;
```

i hope this has helped you.

Comment: Great answer ! can you please help me understand with an example the side-effect of not assigning default constructor i.e. `F.prototype.constructor = F;` ?  What I mean is that I can access all property of `F` as well as `obj` even if I don't reassign . So whats the pitfall ?